# How much cheaper would a high level launch be from a sea level launch?

Tags: launch, atmospheric-drag, delta-v

What is the difference in delta-V required for a launch from the highest natural point on Earth ([about 8,800 m or 29,000 ft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest)) as opposed to a sea level launch?

Assuming a completely [ground based launch system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_loop), air resistance would presumably be a consideration.  This similar question [Effect of atmospheric drag on rocket launches and benefits of high altitude launch sites](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/744/effect-of-atmospheric-drag-on-rocket-launches) is specific to rockets, where lift is generated throughout the transition through the atmosphere.

Comment: It would be very expensive to maintain a space base there, including all infrastructure, and to transfer the payload.

Comment: Cheaper dollar-wise or acceleration-wise?

Comment: Can you provide oxygen masks for all the workers?

Comment: @Undo Accelertion.

Comment: I suggest that @AlanSE simply copies [his answer on that similar question](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/750/49) here, because I don't see how it doesn't answer your question. I'm not saying the question is a duplicate, I'm saying that the answer could easily fit both questions equally well. According to [SE] stuff, this is in certain cases permissible. As he said in the answer: _"The sum of all these is a ballpark estimate of the benefit you would get from changing your launch location from sea-level to Mt. Everest"_ (in terms of Δv, and the savings are then by his calculations 6.167%).

Comment: @TildalWave I would assume there should be a difference, a rocket is going slower in the thicker atmosphere, and faster as it gets to the thinner.  A ground based launch is going fastest in the thickest atmosphere, and slows in the thinner atmosphere.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Well, the figures would change (essentially the path is a hypotenuse instead of a vertical cathetus of a triangle), but the equations stay the same, at least I don't see the reason to use different ones. Alan's answer would need a bit of recalculation to answer your question, but since it's his answer, I thought he'd want to post it?