# Have all spacecraft on record been launched from land?

Tags: launch

Water is a little buoyant which may be part of the reason a lot of commerce happens on the waves.

- How much of a difference in terms of fuel would it make if the craft were launched from a water-body?
- Have all spacecraft to-date launched from land?

Comment: [Sea Launch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Launch). I remember about a satellite launch from a Russian submarine.

Comment: Assuming you are asking about launch from a ship, part of your question is addressed at http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/744/effect-of-atmospheric-drag-on-rocket-launches

Comment: Converted SLBM, such as [Shtil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtil%27)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spacecraft have been launched on Air, Land, and Sea.

**Air Launch**

The most popular of these is the [Pegasus Rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_%28rocket%29) from Orbital. The airplane carrying the rocket goes up to ~40,000 ft, and fires off the rocket from below. These have carried a number of missions, including NASA, commercial, and other sources.

**Sea Launch**

The name of a company which launches such rockets. They utilized the Zenit-3SL rockets for all of their launches, and primarily launched GEO satellites from the equator, which reduces considerably the cost to launch a GEO sat, due to the fact that the inclination doesn't have to be removed.

Answer (score 9):

To add to the existing answers, [this article](http://www.space.com/2440-russian-submarine-launches-russian-microsatellite.html) describes a small satellite launched from a Russian submarine on a [converted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtil%27) submarine-launched ballistic missile (SLBM). The satellite launched was called *Kompass 2*, and it was put into a ~ 400x480 km orbit at around 80 degrees inclination.

The Wikipedia article linked above describes another submarine-based launch in 1998, which placed two payloads into a 400x776 km orbit, again near 80 degrees inclination.

Answer (score 5):

There will not be a difference in fuel consumption  unless the launch site is placed at high altitude (above sea level).

**[Sea launch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Launch)**:

> Thirty-one rockets have been assembled and
>   launched so far, with three failures and one partial failure.

**[Land launch](http://www.sciencepresse.qc.ca/clafleur/Spacecrafts-index.html)**:

According to [this site](http://www.sciencepresse.qc.ca/clafleur/Spacecrafts-index.html) 6851 launches have been conducted by various nations using this technique.