# Is there a known solution for optimal impulsive transfer between two arbitrary elliptical orbits?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, low-energy-transfer

If not, what optimization methods or tools do people use? (Code libraries?)

Comment: Relevant term, "Lambert's problem". The planar case is manageable: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16931/8693