# What would it take to bring VSS Unity over the Kármán line?

Tags: delta-v, booster, sub-orbital, karman-line, virgin-galactic

There's been a great deal debate about [Virgin Galactic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Galactic) calling [50 miles "space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line#Alternatives_to_the_definition), while most use a [100 km Kármán line definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) for the term. [VSS Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Unity) has exceeded 89 km altitude on [two occasions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Unity#List_of_test_flights), including [its latest flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Unity_Unity21). This seems awfully close to 100 km. So, being that Virgin does not use [a vertical trajectory](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27898/14585), what would it take to bring their vehicle another 11 km up?